# Performance difference between res.json() and res.end()

Tags: node.js, optimization, express

I want to send a JSON response using Node and Express. I'm trying to compare the performance of `res.end` and `res.json` for this purpose.

**Version 1: res.json**

```
res.json(anObject);
```

**Version 2: res.end**

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.end(JSON.stringify(anObject));
```

Running some benchmarks I can see that the second version is almost 15% faster than the first one. Is there a particular reason I have to use `res.json` if I want to send a JSON response?

Comment: Interesting that the difference is so large giving that the res.json code does not do much more than your second example: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L154

Comment: res.json has some overhead (extra stack frame, argument parsing, checks settings for `json replacer` and `json spaces`).  I expect you'll find that the runtimes converge as the object you're stringifying gets longer.  I doubt the difference will ever be big enough that its worth worrying about.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, is is very desirable to use `json` despite the overhead.

`setHeader` and `end` come from the [native http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).  By using them, you're effectively bypassing a lot Express's added features, hence the moderate speed bump in a benchmark.

However, benchmarks in isolation don't tell the whole story.  `json` is really just a convenience method that [sets](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.5.1/lib/response.js#L194) the `Content-Type` and then calls `send`.  [`send`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.5.1/lib/response.js#L82) is an extremely useful function because it:

- Supports [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) requests
- Sets the appropriate `Content-Length` header to ensure that the response does not use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which wastes bandwidth.
- Most importantly, provides `ETag` support automatically, allowing conditional `GET`s.

The last point is the biggest benefit of `json` and probably the biggest part of the 15% difference.  Express calculates a CRC32 checksum of the JSON string and adds it as the `ETag` header.  This allows a browser making subsequent requests for the same resource to issue a conditional `GET` (the `If-None-Match` header), and your server will respond `304 Not Modified` if the JSON string is the same, meaning the actual JSON need not be sent over the network again.

This can add up to substantial bandwidth (and thus time) savings.  Because the network is a *much* larger bottleneck than CPU, these savings are almost sure to eclipse the relatively small CPU savings you'd get from skipping `json()`.

---

Finally, there's also the issue of bugs.  Your "version 2" example has a bug.

JSON is stringified as UTF-8, and Chrome (contrary to spec) does not default to handling `application/json` responses as UTF-8; you need to supply a `charset`.  This means non-ASCII characters will be mangled in Chrome.  This issue has already been [discovered](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1631) by Express users, and Express [sets](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1704) the proper header for you.

This is one of the many reasons to be careful of premature/micro-optimization.  You run the very real risk of introducing bugs.

Comment: Amazingly in-depth answer.  I was hoping someone who knew more about express would do better than my comment.  One thing: "these savings are sure to eclipse..." this is not true if you know you're not sending something cache-able.  Of course, the bugs issue still remains and I agree with your conclusion regardless.

Comment: That's true, but notwithstanding CPU is rarely the first bottleneck you'll hit.  Skipping `json()` in favor of rolling your own is not a good place to look for optimizations unless you can prove it is a problem in your app.  (And because this is a strictly CPU-bound problem, the correct answer is probably "more servers" anyway.)